# Store outputs of forecast

Tags: forecasting

I'm using a forecast() function in R many times with loop (12 months) for but I want to use accuracy to compare forecast for horizon time =12 and one-step ahead. My problem is how to store the results of 12 times to use it in accuracy.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: here is the code :  for ( i in 1:12) {
  demfit <- ets(Dem2)
  f<-forecast(demfit,1)
  Dem2[length(Dem2)+1]=f$mean[1] 
}
accuracy(f,Test) #it's only for the last forecasted value (12) but I'm looking to compute accuracy for 12 forecast. It the same thing for this :
fit<-ets(Dem2)
f1<-forecast(fit,12)
accuracy(f1,Test)

Comment: Please read the link I provided, make your example *reproducible* (that is, so we can run it locally), edit it into your question and explain what exactly you want. Thank you.